# Saving Images in Cell Array (Matlab) into different files

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, cell-array

I have a 1x7049 Cell Array. Each of the elements of this array is a 96x96 matrix.

Now, I want to save each of these 96x96 matrices into jpg files, so that I will get 7049 images. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this by iterating the cell array with a loop and save each image into a separate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop

```
for ii = 1:numel(myCellArr)
    fileName = sprintf('image_%04d.jpg');
    imwrite( myCellArr{ii}, fileName );
end
```